# Why does range(start, end) not include end?

Tags: python, range

```
>>> range(1,11)
```

gives you

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Why not 1-11?

Did they just decide to do it like that at random or does it have some value I am not seeing?

Comment: read Dijkstra, ewd831

Comment: Basically you are choosing one set of off-by-one bugs for another. One set are more likely to cause your loops to terminate early, the other is likely to cause an Exception (or buffer overflow in other languages). Once you have written a bunch of code, you will see that the choice of behaviour `range()` has makes sense much more often

Comment: Link to Dijkstra, ewd831: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF

Comment: @sundar Dijkstras argument is that the convention `a < i <= b` is the only one for which `a` and `b` never need to leave the set of natural numbers, as long as the range of `i` is either empty or within the set of natural numbers. Although a mostly cosmetic argument, I think it's a perfectly valid one.

Comment: @andreasdr But even if the cosmetic argument is valid, doesn't Python's approach introduce a new problem of readability? In common-usage English the term "range" implies that something ranges *from* something *to* something -- like an interval. That len(list(range(1,2))) returns 1 and len(list(range(2))) returns 2 is something you really have to learn to digest.

Comment: Another freaky Python convention borrowed. :P I prefer simulating natural intuition and not to make something like January[0], February[1], etc.

Comment: It would be nice if range() offered an option for inclusive upper bound. I'm fine with range() being exclusive by default, but there are situations where inclusive makes syntax more readable.

Comment: @Shuklaswag I think range(start, end+1) would be much more readable than range(start, end, end_exclusive=False) or any variation thereof.

Comment: @sundar-ReinstateMonica "Easily argued against." How?

Comment: If a person said they want a range of colors from green to red, then very few people would say they don't want red. So the Eng word range is not appropriate word. This is not going to change but i think this is a chink in the armor that python is a sensible language.

Comment: The Range function in R returns the minimum and maximum value from the input vector

Comment: Ruby implementation for range: (1..5)  => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and (1...5) => 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: I've written a bunch of code and that choice of behavior of `range` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Though it was a fairly close call, I decided that the other question is a better canonical duplicate, even though it is currently much less popular. The deciding factor is that the other question is at the *appropriate level of generality*: it mentions other constructs (`slice` objects and the slicing operator) that work the same way for the same reason, without making the question harder to answer.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Because it's more common to call `range(0, 10)` which returns `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` which contains 10 elements which equals `len(range(0, 10))`. Remember that programmers prefer 0-based indexing.

Also, consider the following common code snippet:

```
for i in range(len(li)):
    pass
```

Could you see that if `range()` went up to exactly `len(li)` that this would be problematic? The programmer would need to explicitly subtract 1. This also follows the common trend of programmers preferring `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` over `for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)`.

If you are calling range with a start of 1 frequently, you might want to define your own function:

```
>>> def range1(start, end):
...     return range(start, end+1)
...
>>> range1(1, 10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: If that were the reasoning wouldn't the parameters be `range(start, count)`?

Comment: ah, so really it's because x can be 0

Comment: @shogun The start value defaults to 0, i.e. `range(10)` is equivalent to `range(0, 10)`.

Comment: Your `range1` will not work with ranges that have a different step size than `1`.

Comment: You explain that range(x) should start with 0 and x will be the "length of the range". OK. But you didn't explain why range(x,y) should start with x and end with y-1. If the programmer wants a for-loop with i ranging from 1 to 3, he has to explicitly add 1. Is this really about convenience?

Comment: The "length of the range" argument doesn't apply when the step is not equal to 1. i.e. `range(0, 10, 2)` is `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]` which obviously doesn't have 10 elements. I suppose it would have `end / step` elements, rounding down of course.

Comment: Even though this is old, something as simple as adding +1 in range, solved my problem.

Comment: @dimo414 Its pretty simple to have an additional parameter as step for range function to work.
`range1 = lambda start,end,step: range(start,end+1,step)
for i in range(1,26):
    print(i)
for i in range1(1,25,3):
    print(i)`

Comment: `for i in range(len(li)):` is rather an antipattern. One should use `enumerate`.

Comment: "prefer" is a strong word

Comment: Programmers do prefer 0-based indexing, which is why it's bizarre that Python uses 1-based indexing for stop positions. I don't know many computing languages, but they've all had only one convention. Python has two. The for-loop examples here are deceptive. When I write "5:12", or "range(5, 12, 3)", I mean "go from 5 to 12". If I wanted 11, that's what I would have written. In Python, you use a number to represent the number before it... but only sometimes.

Comment: this is where Ruby shines:  (1..10) vs (1...10)

Comment: @bzip2 Programmers don't _prefer_, they are _taught_ that in computer science, due to some conventions, most things are indexed with 0. One may as well create an equivalent set of equally valid conventions where objects are indexed starting from 3512 (or any other number), as well as there are equally valid arithmetics and axiomatic mathematics.

Comment: It's a right-open interval rather then (start, count) because those are nicer to work with. For example contiguous ranges have corresponding end/start values. E.g. this in set of ranges `[0, 8) [8, 32), [64, 128)` it's easier to see that the first two are contiguous and the next two aren't than `(0, 8), (8, 24), (64, 64)`. Using right-open intervals is completely standard in programming. Counts are generally only used for entire containers (e.g. `std::vector` in C++).

Comment: Then the problem is that Python (and some other programming languages) use the illogical, confusing and unnatural 0-indexing. And they need to compensate it with tricks as exclusive boundaries.
Most scientific languages, such as R, Matlab, Julia, Fortran, Mathematica, Lua, PL/I, Maple, Sage, APL...  use 1-indexing, the same than mathematicians, physicists and engineers.

Answer (score 86):

Although there are some useful algorithmic explanations here, I think it may help to add some simple 'real life' reasoning as to why it works this way, which I have found useful when introducing the subject to young newcomers:

With something like 'range(1,10)' confusion can arise from thinking that pair of parameters represents the "start and end".

It is actually start and "stop".

Now, if it ***were*** the "end" value then, yes, you might expect that number would be included as the final entry in the sequence. But it is not the "end".

Others mistakenly call that parameter "count" because if you only ever use 'range(n)' then it does, of course, iterate 'n' times. This logic breaks down when you add the start parameter.

So the key point is to remember its name: "**stop**".
That means it is the point at which, when reached, iteration will stop immediately. Not ***after*** that point.

So, while "start" does indeed represent the first value to be included, on reaching the "stop" value it 'breaks' rather than continuing to process 'that one as well' before stopping.

One analogy that I have used in explaining this to kids is that, ironically, it is better behaved than kids! It doesn't stop *after* it supposed to - it stops immediately without finishing what it was doing. (They get this ;) )

Another analogy - when you drive a car you don't ***pass*** a stop/yield/'give way' sign and end up with it sitting somewhere next to, or behind, your car. Technically you still haven't reached it when you do stop. It is not included in the 'things you passed on your journey'.

I hope some of that helps in explaining to Pythonitos/Pythonitas!

Comment: This explanation is more intuitive. Thanks

Comment: Love the stop sign analogy, sorry to steal it :)

Comment: @nyholku Sorry for that! I have now deleted my comment. It was a harsh response to a harsh comment, which had already been deleted too, so keeping it is completely pointless, especially if it makes other people feel bad for nothing. Technologies should be tools for making great things rather than be apples of discord.

Comment: @ArthurKhazbs that [deleting] was an act of integrity! Well done. I will delete my comment, though it was kind tongue in cheek. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 27):

Exclusive ranges do have some benefits:

For one thing each item in `range(0,n)` is a valid index for lists of length `n`.

Also `range(0,n)` has a length of `n`, not `n+1` which an inclusive range would.

Comment: This is a common explanation, but it is not a good one. If range is inclusive at both ends, users could easily use range(0, n-1) or range(1, n) to generate n numbers.

Answer (score 22):

It's also useful for splitting ranges; `range(a,b)` can be split into `range(a, x)` and `range(x, b)`, whereas with inclusive range you would write either `x-1` or `x+1`. While you rarely need to split ranges, you do tend to split lists quite often, which is one of the reasons slicing a list `l[a:b]` includes the a-th element but not the b-th. Then `range` having the same property makes it nicely consistent.

Answer (score 20):

It works well in combination with zero-based indexing and `len()`. For example, if you have 10 items in a list `x`, they are numbered 0-9. `range(len(x))` gives you 0-9.

Of course, people will tell you it's more Pythonic to do `for item in x` or `for index, item in enumerate(x)` rather than `for i in range(len(x))`.

Slicing works that way too: `foo[1:4]` is items 1-3 of `foo` (keeping in mind that item 1 is actually the second item due to the zero-based indexing). For consistency, they should both work the same way.

I think of it as: "the first number you want, followed by the first number you *don't* want." If you want 1-10, the first number you don't want is 11, so it's `range(1, 11)`.

If it becomes cumbersome in a particular application, it's easy enough to write a little helper function that adds 1 to the ending index and calls `range()`.

Comment: Agree on slicing.  `w = 'abc'; w[:] == w[0:len(w)]; w[:-1] == w[0:len(w)-1];`

Comment: `def full_range(start,stop): return range(start,stop+1) ## helper function`

Answer (score 12):

The length of the range is the top value minus the bottom value.

It's very similar to something like:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    //i goes from 1 to 10 in here
}
```

in a C-style language.

Also like Ruby's range:

```
1...11 #this is a range from 1 to 10
```

However, Ruby recognises that many times you'll want to include the terminal value and offers the alternative syntax:

```
1..10 #this is also a range from 1 to 10
```

Answer (score 8):

Consider the code

```
for i in range(10):
    print "You'll see this 10 times", i
```

The idea is that you get a list of length `y-x`, which you can (as you see above) iterate over.

Read up on [the python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) for range - they consider for-loop iteration the primary usecase.

Comment: Simplest explanation. logging in just to upvote

Answer (score 6):

Basically in python `range(n)` iterates `n` times, which is of exclusive nature that is why it does not give last value when it is being printed, we can create a function which gives 
inclusive value it means it will also print last value mentioned in range.

```python
def main():
    for i in inclusive_range(25):
        print(i, sep=" ")


def inclusive_range(*args):
    numargs = len(args)
    if numargs == 0:
        raise TypeError("you need to write at least a value")
    elif numargs == 1:
        stop = args[0]
        start = 0
        step = 1
    elif numargs == 2:
        (start, stop) = args
        step = 1
    elif numargs == 3:
        (start, stop, step) = args
    else:
        raise TypeError("Inclusive range was expected at most 3 arguments,got {}".format(numargs))
    i = start
    while i <= stop:
        yield i
        i += step


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: To avoid the possible surprise of an endless loop, I suggest to improve this code so that it works also in case of a negative step value.

Answer (score 5):

The `range(n)` in python returns from 0 to n-1. Respectively, the `range(1,n)` from 1 to n-1.
So, if you want to omit the first value and get also the last value (n) you can do it very simply using the following code.

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print(i) #prints from 1 to n
```

Comment: The OP knows how to obtain the extra value, they are asking about the reason it is not included by default.

Answer (score 1):

It's just more convenient to reason about in many cases.

Basically, we could think of a range as an interval between `start` and `end`. If `start <= end`, the length of the interval between them  is `end - start`. If `len` was actually defined as the length, you'd have:

```
len(range(start, end)) == start - end
```

However, we count the integers included in the range instead of measuring the length of the interval. To keep the above property true, we should include one of the endpoints and exclude the other.

Adding the `step` parameter is like introducing a unit of length. In that case, you'd expect

```
len(range(start, end, step)) == (start - end) / step
```

for length. To get the count, you just use integer division.

Comment: These defenses of Python's inconsistency are hilarious. If I wanted the interval between two numbers, why would I use subtraction to get the difference instead of the interval? It's inconsistent to use different indexing conventions for start and end positions. Why would you need to write "5:22" in order to get positions 5 to 21?

Comment: It's not Python's, it's pretty common across the board. In C, Java, Ruby, you name it

Comment: I meant to say that it's common for indexing, not that the other languages necessarily have the same exact kind of object

Comment: @Arseny in defence of Ruby, this is not true. You can construct inclusive and exclusive ranges in Ruby: `(3..5).include?(5) => true` but `(3...5).include?(5) => false`. Array slicing is explicit and inclusive: `[0,1,2,3,4].slice(0,2) => [0, 1]`. You can even construct open ranges: `r = 42..; r.include?(Float::INFINITY) => true`

Comment: @AndreasGebhard, no doubt there are cases when that's convenient. Scala, for instance, has both `a to b` and `a until b`. My point is that excluding the right end of the range is common practice and isn't an inconsistency whatsoever. Also, historically, the `<` comparison is faster for the processor than the `<=` comparison

Comment: @Arseny I agree that excluding the right end of the range is common, and I do not judge Python to adopt this practice. For me, this is fine. I can use inclusive ranges in Ruby now and five minutes later I can use exclusive ranges in Python and still like them both. I just wanted to say that citing Ruby as an example for right-exclusive ranges is slightly simplified because Ruby gives you both, like Scala.

Answer (score 0):

Two major uses of ranges in python. All things tend to fall in one or the other

1. integer. Use built-in: `range(start, stop, step)`. To have `stop` included would mean that the end step would be assymetric for the general case. Consider  `range(0,5,3)`. If default behaviour would output 5 at the end, it would be broken.
2. floating pont. This is for numerical uses (where sometimes it happens to be integers too). Then use `numpy.linspace`.