# How do I write a program that asks a user for 2 numbers and then prints a list of even numbers between those numbers?

Tags: python

I'm using JES. The function below will work for what I want it to do, but it doesn't include x and y in the answer. For example, if the first number I enter is 2 and the second number is 8, it prints only 4 and 6. I want it to print 2, 4, 6, 8. Please help! Thanks!

```
def main():
  x=input("Enter the first number:")
  y=input("Enter the second number:")
  i=0
  for i in range (x,y):
    if i%2==0:
      print i
```

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment?

Comment: The code you posted does not skip the first number input, only the last...

Comment: Yes I realized that it doesn't skip the first number only the last one after I made the post. Oops. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, the problem is that, in Python (and, by extension, JES), `range(x, y)` steps from `x` to `y-1`, inclusive. This allows it to naturally mimic the slicing syntax of the `[]` list operator, i.e. `[l[a] for a in range(x, y)]` is the same list as `l[x:y]`. (As for *why* both slicing and `range` do this, see [Why does range(start, end) not include end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end)).

So, if you want `x` to `y` inclusive, you just need to bump the last parameter up by one:

```
for i in range(x, y+1):
```

and it should print out the numbers you want.

P.S. the `i=0` before the loop is unnecessary. The `for` loop will initialize (and create if necessary) the variable `i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
print ",".join([str(i) for i in range(int(raw_input("Enter #1:")),\
                                      int(raw_input("Enter #2:"))+1) if not i%2])
```

I think I got those parens right

alternatively,Using `input` is shorter but a huge security hole and should usually be avoided

```
print ",".join([str(i) for i in range(input("Enter #1:"),\
                                      input("Enter #2:")+1) if not i%2])
```

and the shortest (thanks nneonneo)

```
print str([x for x in range(input('1'), input('2')+1) if not x%2])[1:-1]
```

Comment: Someone had to do and add the one-liner...you should replace `int(raw_input)` with `input` for brevity (security here is not a concern!)

Comment: `input` is horrible.... but yes that would be shorter :P

Comment: It's horrible, unless it does what you want it to do and you understand the ramifications.

I submit that `print str([x for x in range(input('1'), input('2')) if not x%2])[1:-1]` is a shorter, though somewhat less readable one-liner :)

Comment: "Security here is not a concern!" Maybe, but it's a good idea to get into the habit of writing secure code, even for frivolous example/toy code.