# Delete the first three rows of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to delete the first three rows of a dataframe in pandas.

I know `df.ix[:-1]` would remove the last row, but I can't figure out how to remove first n rows.

Comment: For read_csv/read_html you can use e.g. `header=3` constructor argument which will set that row as the header row: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822697/191246

Answer (score 457, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html):

```
df = df.iloc[3:]
```

will give you a new df without the first three rows.

Comment: doesn't that remove the first 4 rows instead the first 3 rows in the original question?

Comment: No, It doesn't. The start position of the slice is always included.

Comment: Anyone happen to know how to do this in a `groupby()`? This works but returns duplicate columns in the index `df=pd.DataFrame({'v':np.arange(10).tolist()*2,'g':['a']*10+['b']*10});df.groupby('g').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[3:])`

Comment: So if you want to delete from row 3 to row 9, for example, how would you do it? `df=df.iloc[3:9]`?

Comment: @M.K if using this approach, you can use this in combination with `pd.concat()`. Something like, `df2 = pd.concat([df.iloc[:3],df.iloc[10:]])`.

Comment: If you do this first row will be 3, how can I make it so it starts from 0.

Comment: @makewhite you can use `df = df.iloc[3:].reset_index(drop=True)` to reset the index to 0.

Answer (score 135):

I think a more explicit way of doing this is to use drop.

The syntax is:

```
df.drop(label)
```

And as pointed out by @tim and @ChaimG, this can be done in-place:

```
df.drop(label, inplace=True)
```

One way of implementing this could be:

```
df.drop(df.index[:3], inplace=True)
```

And another "in place" use:

```
df.drop(df.head(3).index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: `drop` can even be calculated in-place (without extra assignment). Faster and simpler!

Comment: To expand on Tim's idea, Example: `df.drop(label, inplace=True)`

Comment: Due to index 0, I believe the implementation suggestion will delete 4 rows.

Comment: @DanielMorgan That is not the case as python ranges are half open. As to why that is, is another question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end or https://www.quora.com/Why-are-Python-ranges-half-open-exclusive-instead-of-closed-inclusive

Comment: @tim, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532302/pandas-peculiar-performance-drop-for-inplace-rename-after-dropna/22533110#22533110), `inplace` operations are not faster. Also, simpler is a matter of opinion: I find it easier to read when the code doesn't have `inplace` parameters.

Comment: @toto_tico Afaik, inplace operations are ideally intended to avoid duplication in memory. That can be a big deal for a large object. Even if an old implementation uses a copy, an ideal implementation can avoid a copy.

Answer (score 16):

```
df = df.iloc[n:]
```

n drops the first n rows.

Answer (score 12):

A simple way is to use tail(-n) to remove the first n rows

`df=df.tail(-3)`

Answer (score 8):

```
df.drop(df.index[[0,2]])
```

Pandas uses zero based numbering, so 0 is the first row, 1 is the second row and 2 is the third row.

Answer (score 7):

You can use python slicing, but note it's not in-place.

```
In [15]: import pandas as pd
In [16]: import numpy as np
In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,2)))
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
          0         1
0  0.294077  0.229471
1  0.949007  0.790340
2  0.039961  0.720277
3  0.401468  0.803777
4  0.539951  0.763267

In [19]: df[3:]
Out[19]:
          0         1
3  0.401468  0.803777
4  0.539951  0.763267
```

Comment: what does not in-place mean in `pandas`?

Comment: They're talking about the `inplace` parameter that shows up in many methods in pandas.

Answer (score 5):

inp0= pd.read_csv("bank_marketing_updated_v1.csv",skiprows=2)

or if you want to do in existing dataframe

simply do following command

Answer (score 0):

#### Flexible truncation in pandas with [`truncate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html)

To remove the first N rows

```
df.truncate(before=N)
```

To remove the last M rows

```
df.truncate(after=M)
```

To remove the first N and last M rows together

```
df.truncate(before=N, after=M)
```

To remove the first N columns

```
df.truncate(before=N, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer, but I think the simplest way to remove the first 3 rows would just be:

```
df = df[3:]
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple way to implement that by the [**drop**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) command.

```py
df = df.drop(3)
```

Comment: Hi, Aman. Please wrap code examples in code blocks for clarity ([see guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)). It also helps to reference documentation pages to help the questioner understand the method.

Comment: this will fail if your  index is not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  for example.