# Can't drop NAN with dropna in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I import pandas as pd and run the code below and get the following result

Code:

```
traindataset = pd.read_csv('/Users/train.csv')
print traindataset.dtypes
print traindataset.shape
print traindataset.iloc[25,3]
traindataset.dropna(how='any')
print traindataset.iloc[25,3]
print traindataset.shape
```

Output

```
TripType                   int64  
VisitNumber                int64  
Weekday                   object  
Upc                      float64  
ScanCount                  int64  
DepartmentDescription     object  
FinelineNumber           float64  
dtype: object

(647054, 7)

nan  
nan

(647054, 7) 
[Finished in 2.2s]
```

From the result, the dropna line doesn't work because the row number doesn't change and there is still NAN in the dataframe. How that comes? I am craaaazy right now.

Answer (score 33):

You need to read [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) (emphasis added):

> **Return** object with labels on given axis omitted

`dropna` *returns* a *new* DataFrame.  If you want it to modify the existing DataFrame, all you have to do is read further in the documentation:

> **inplace** : boolean, default False
>
> If True, do operation inplace and return None.

So to modify it in place, do `traindataset.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)`.

Comment: Thanks. I got confused by the example of "dropna" from the tutorial.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comment: All the tutorials I found shot a df before and after dropna on the same object. Anyway +1, thank you!

Answer (score 20):

[`pd.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) uses `inplace=False` by default. This is the norm with *most* Pandas operations; exceptions do exist, e.g. [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html).

Therefore, you must either assign back to your variable, *or* state explicitly `inplace=True`:

```
df = df.dropna(how='any')           # assign back
df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)  # set inplace parameter
```

Stylistically, the former is often preferred as it supports operator chaining, and the latter often [does not yield any or significant performance benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533110/9209546).

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can also use `notnull()` method to select the rows which are not `null`.

For example if you want to select Non `null` values from columns `country` and `variety` of the dataframe reviews:

```
answer=reviews.loc[(reviews.country.notnull()) & (reviews.variety.notnull())]
```

But here we are just selecting relevant data;to remove `null` values you should use `dropna()` method.

Answer (score 6):

This is my first post. I just spent a few hours debugging this exact issue and I would like to share how I fixed this issue.

I was converting my entire dataframe to a string and then placing that value back into the dataframe using similar code to what is displayed below: (please note, the code below will only convert the value to a string)

```
row_counter = 0
for ind, row in dataf.iterrows():
    cell_value = str(row['column_header'])
    dataf.loc[row_counter, 'column_header'] = cell_value
    row_counter += 1
```

After converting the entire dataframe to a string, I then used the `dropna()` function. The values that were previously `NaN` (considered a null value by pandas) were converted to the string `'nan'`.

In conclusion, drop blank values FIRST, before you start manipulating data in the CSV and converting its data type.