# Reshaping for Pearsonr correlation

Tags: pandas, correlation, pearson-correlation

What is the best way to delete and match length of datasets when doing a pearsonr correlation?

I am currently running a pearsonr correlation on returns and various fundamental indicator only issue is when I have nans and when I run it I get nan when I dropna() I have different size datasets and get an error regarding the shapes. 
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (469099,) (539093,)

Comment: I know I cant replace them with other values but is there anyway to minimize the length of the columns so they can equal each other

Comment: You shouldn't drop `NaN` values from each array separately, otherwise you ruin pairing of observations and your correlation is meaningless.

Comment: If your two datasets are stored in different columns of the same Pandas DataFrame, `dropna()` will (by default) drop the rows in which any value is nan, which is apparently what you want.  So it sounds like your datasets are not stored in a single DataFrame.  In that case, you'll have to make sure that when you drop a value from one dataset, you also drop the corresponding value from the other dataset.  Or, put them into two columns of one DataFrame, and then use `dropna()`.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it \

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear on the question what you are trying to do; however, I assume you are trying to drop 'Na' from the data so the both sets match in shape. If you are running dropna(), make sure to set 'inplace = True' as a parameter or to assign it to a dataframe.

Either

```
df.dropna(inplace = True)
```

or

```
df = df.dropna()
```

You can also check: [Can't drop NAN with dropna in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643843/cant-drop-nan-with-dropna-in-pandas)