# Nan does not drop out in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which is shown below:
[image]

I want to drop out all the record that has nan in 'Rego' column. I tried few commands such as

```
temp_df = temp_df[temp_df['Rego'].notnull()]
temp_df = temp_df[temp_df['Rego'].notna()]
t = temp_df.loc[temp_df['Rego'].notnull()]
temp_df.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
temp_df.dropna(how ='any',inplace=True)
```

but none of the above commands drop nan values from the Rego column. I looked into existing threads of the forum ([Can't drop NAN with dropna in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643843/cant-drop-nan-with-dropna-in-pandas)) but couldn't fix the issue. Could anyone guide me where am I making the mistake?

Comment: That is likely not a `NaN`, it is a *string* with as content `nan`, so `'nan'`. You can filter that with `temp_df[temp_df['Rego'] != 'nan']`.

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(temp_df.iloc[4]['Rego']))`? You ideally want this to return `NoneType` if your data is correctly represented as a `NaN`. I suspect, as @WillemVanOnsem mentioned, you actually have the data stored as a `str` type which won't work with the `.dropna()` methods.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for pointing out the mistake. You guys are right its string. I just realized that.  have been struggling to fix this issue for about two hours. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: @gbeaven Thanks you saved my day. The output of print statement is <class 'str'>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe some nan value is a str, so do this first:

```
temp_df['Rego'].replace('nan',np.nan,inplace=True)
```

Then now you can do:

```
temp_df_fitered=temp_df[temp_df['Rego'].notnull()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the result to a dataframe. This may work:

```
temp_df=temp_df.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
```