# pandas: Notnull() or Notna() does not drop Nan value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains two columns (as shown in the figure).
[image]

I am trying to drop Nan from one of the columns (i.e. FACILITYID). I tried to use the following commands to drop the NaN

```
temp = temp[temp['FACILITYID'].notnull()]
temp = temp[temp['FACILITYID'].notna()]
temp = temp[~temp['FACILITYID'].isnull()]
temp = temp[~temp['FACILITYID'].isna()]
temp = temp[temp['FACILITYID']!='']
```

However, none of them remove NaN. I followed the instruction of the existing thread ([Nan does not drop out in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420868/nan-does-not-drop-out-in-python/58421136#58421136)) but no luck. Could anyone point out where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the elements printed as *NaN* contain just a **string**
composed of these 3 letters.
Maybe all other values in this column are also strings (not numbers).

If it was "real" *NaN* then the column would have been coerced to
*float* (because *NaN* is a special case of *float*) and
all numeric values would have  been terminated with "*.0*".

To verify the type of each column run:

```
temp.info()
```

The printout will contain a row concerning each row (name, the number of
non-null values and the type).
Caution for *string* column the type is printed as *object*.

Comment: Thanks. I ran the temp.info() and both columns are object data type. Shall I just use astype() function to convert into float?

Comment: Run *temp.FACILITYID = pd.to_numeric(temp.FACILITYID, errors='coerce')*. *temp.FACILITYID.astype('float')* also does the job.

Comment: I ran the command but it throws an error message "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'temp'.

Comment: From your picture I see that *temp* is a **DataFrame**, not a **Series**. Run *type(temp)* to check it.

Comment: it is data frame.  when I run the type command it gives "<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>"

Comment: Maybe you have some older version of *Pandas*, not allowing *temp.FACILITYID*
redaction. Change to *temp['FACILITYID']* (in each case).
Another hint: Upgrade your *Pandas* installation, then maybe the
original redaction will work.