# In-place version of pandas truncate?

Tags: python, pandas

Newbie question: is there an in-place version of pandas truncate?

For example

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'stuff':range(5)}, index=range(5))
>>> df.truncate(2,3)
```

returns a new truncated data frame. I could do

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'stuff':range(5)}, index=range(5))
>>> df = df.truncate(2,3)
```

but that seems inefficient. Is there a way to do a more efficient truncate which does not make a copy but does the truncate in-place? Or is this kind of efficiency not an issue due to some uber-clever pandas design?

Note, that the docstring for truncate says there is a copy option, but I do not think that affects whether the dataframe itself is truncated but whether the returned value is a copy of the data frame or a reference to a portion of the data frame. See below for what I mean:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'stuff':range(5)}, index=range(5))
>>> cp = df.truncate(2,3, copy=False)
>>> df
   stuff
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
>>> cp['stuff'][2] = -50
>>> df
   stuff
0      0
1      1
2    -50
3      3
4      4
```

Notice that when we use `copy=False` df is still not truncated but the returned object is a slice of df which when modified also modifies df.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you even read the docstring?

Comment: @Goyo I'm guessing you are referring to the copy option mentioned in the docstring. Sorry for not being clearer in the initial post. The copy option is not the same as inplace truncation. Updated question to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22533110/2285236

Answer (score 2):

There is no truncate in-place, but the inefficiency associated with making the copy can be avoided using `copy=False` (if the copy can be avoided at all, which is not always the case):

`df = df.truncate(2,3, copy=False)`

If you keep a reference to the original object it will remain unchanged though, as you discovered.

Note that in-place operations and copies are actually unrelated. In-place operations can copy the data and update some internal reference while mnethods that leave the object unchanged do not always have to copy the data.