# Why DataFrame.sort_index retuns None?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have tried to sort data frame by index and have None as result. Why it happens?
This is my data frame http://screencast.com/t/zOEuR6Uu
And I call:

```
levelData.sort_index(inplace = True)
```

None (((

```
 levelData.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 525 entries, 1 to 99
Data columns (total 2 columns):
win       525 non-null int64
action    525 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 12.3+ KB
```

Comment: I'm guessing that it gets sorted in place ... Since it's mutating the original object (`levelData`), there is nothing to return that you don't already have an easy handle on.

Comment: Try `levelData.sort_index(axis = 1, inplace = True)`

Comment: @NickilMaveli I tried it, but its not work

Comment: @Merlin yes, you guess

Comment: @OleksandraK, and levelData.head()  And with head edit new table to show the sort you want.

Comment: Index: 525 entries, 1 to 99, looks strange.

Answer (score 5):

`DataFrame.sort_index` is following the [Command-Query separation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) which says that a function should either be a command or a query but not both.

- Commands do something such as modify the caller (e.g. the DataFrame) *and should return `None`*. (In languages that allow it, commands should return nothing. But since all functions return something in Python, the convention is to return `None`.)
- Queries compute and return a result *but do not modify the caller*.

`inplace=True` makes `sort_index` a command. The method modifies the calling DataFrame and in keeping with the Command-Query principle, returns `None`.

`inplace=False` (the default) makes `sort_index` a query. 
Thus, if you want `sort_index` to return a DataFrame, remove the `inplace=True`.

---

Truly ["inplace" operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) like `list.sort` modify the original data *without* using auxilliary data structures. In this sense, no Pandas operation is truly inplace. When `inplace=True` is used, the result is first computed in an auxilliary data structure (e.g. another DataFrame), and then the underlying data is copied into the shell of the original DataFrame. So

```
df.sort_level(inplace=True)
```

is equivalent to

```
df = df.sort_level()
```

`inplace=True` exists mainly because of the inertia of history. 
The lead developer of Pandas, [Jeff Reback says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533110/190597):

> My personal opinion: I never use in-place operations. The syntax is harder to read and its does not offer any advantages.

Comment: when I remove  inplace=True data frame does not change after sort_index

Comment: @OleksandraK: Of course it doesn't. The new dataframe is returned from the function instead in this case *as stated very clearly at the start of this answer*.