# Pandas dataframe fillna() only some columns in place

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fill none values in a Pandas dataframe with 0's for only some subset of columns.

When I do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,2,3,None],'b':[4,5,None,6],'c':[None,None,7,8]})
print df
df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
print df
```

The output:

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  2.0  5.0  NaN
2  3.0  NaN  7.0
3  NaN  6.0  8.0
     a    b    c
0  1.0  4.0  0.0
1  2.0  5.0  0.0
2  3.0  0.0  7.0
3  0.0  6.0  8.0
```

It replaces every `None` with `0`'s. What I want to do is, only replace `None`s in columns `a` and `b`, but not `c`.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Would be great if more pandas methods having inplace also had include and exclude (subset of columns). And regex for that matter.

Answer (score 417, accepted):

You can select your desired columns and do it by assignment:

```
df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a','b']].fillna(value=0)
```

The resulting output is as expected:

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  2.0  5.0  NaN
2  3.0  0.0  7.0
3  0.0  6.0  8.0
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want! Thank you. Any ways to do this inplace? My original dataframe is pretty big.

Comment: I don't think there is any performance gain by doing this in place as you're overwriting the orig df anyway

Comment: The loc is superfluous here, `df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a','b']].fillna(value=0)` will still work

Comment: @EdChum Doesn't it produce a temporary data frame and hence need more memory to do so? (I am concerned more about memory than time complexity.)

Comment: but you have to produce a temp df at some point in the process in case it borks part way through so there is really no performance difference here between assigning back to yourself and using `inplace=True`

Comment: For many operations, `inplace` will still work on a copy.  I don't know if it's the case for `fillna` or not.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22533110/3339965) from one of the pandas core developers.

Comment: @EdChum Thanks, I've removed the `loc`.  I've conditioned myself to always use `loc` just to play it safe!

Comment: No problem.  I actually was thinking about the same thing you were earlier today in regards to `inplace`, and happened to find the link.  That's some nice coincidental timing!

Comment: This just returns the two columns, but not `c`, which is an issue if you're chaining. For example: `df[['a', 'b']].fillna('').groupby(['a', 'b'])`, the `fillna` ensures that otherwise skipped `NaN`s are also included. If you don't chain, I suggest using `df[['a', 'b']].fillna('', inplace=True)` anyway. Alternatively: `df.fillna({'a':'','b':''}).groupby(['a', 'b'])`

Answer (score 205):

You can using `dict` , `fillna` with different value for different column

```
df.fillna({'a':0,'b':0})
Out[829]: 
     a    b    c
0  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  2.0  5.0  NaN
2  3.0  0.0  7.0
3  0.0  6.0  8.0
```

After assign it back

```
df=df.fillna({'a':0,'b':0})
df
Out[831]: 
     a    b    c
0  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  2.0  5.0  NaN
2  3.0  0.0  7.0
3  0.0  6.0  8.0
```

Comment: really cool, Btw for the dict you can use `fromkeys` if you want, +1

Comment: The answer/example would be clearer if it actually showed different values for the different columns.

Comment: @RufusVS that is right , but still try to match the op's expected output

Comment: This is the better solution that the accepted answer, because it avoids chained indexing issues, e.g. if used with `df.fillna({'a':0,'b':0}, inplace=True)`

Comment: How to use methods like `ffill` or `bfill` inside a dictionary?

Answer (score 55):

You can avoid making a copy of the object using Wen's solution and inplace=True:

```py
df.fillna({'a':0, 'b':0}, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Which yields:

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  2.0  5.0  NaN
2  3.0  0.0  7.0
3  0.0  6.0  8.0
```

Comment: While this is correct, avoiding a copy [isn't necessarily better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533110/9209546).

Answer (score 19):

using the top answer produces a warning about making changes to a copy of a df slice. Assuming that you have other columns, a better way to do this is to pass a dictionary: 
`df.fillna({'A': 'NA', 'B': 'NA'}, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 12):

This should work and without copywarning

```
df[['a', 'b']] = df.loc[:,['a', 'b']].fillna(value=0)
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's how you can do it all in one line:

```
df[['a', 'b']].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

Breakdown: `df[['a', 'b']]` selects the columns you want to fill NaN values for, `value=0` tells it to fill NaNs with zero, and `inplace=True` will make the changes permanent, without having to make a copy of the object.

Comment: Somehow this gives SettingWithCopyWarning and the change is not reflected in `df`.

Comment: Is there a way to fillna(0) on every column to the right of the nth column?

Answer (score 6):

For some odd reason this DID NOT work (using Pandas: '0.25.1')

```
df[['col1', 'col2']].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

Another solution:

```
subset_cols = ['col1','col2']
[df[col].fillna(0, inplace=True) for col in subset_cols]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[1,2,np.nan,], 'col2':[1,np.nan,3], 'col3':[np.nan,2,3]})
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0  1.00  1.00   nan
1  2.00   nan  2.00
2   nan  3.00  3.00
```

Apply list comp. to fillna values:

```
subset_cols = ['col1','col2']
[df[col].fillna(0, inplace=True) for col in subset_cols]
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0  1.00  1.00   nan
1  2.00  0.00  2.00
2  0.00  3.00  3.00
```

Comment: I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529)

Comment: So the best should be if raise `inplace` warning and then removed from pandas in my opinion.

Comment: So easy advice - always avoid inplace and never such problem here ;)

Answer (score 5):

Or something like:

```
df.loc[df['a'].isnull(),'a']=0
df.loc[df['b'].isnull(),'b']=0
```

and if there is more:

```
for i in your_list:
    df.loc[df[i].isnull(),i]=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this syntax wont work:

```
df[['col1','col2']] = df[['col1','col2']].fillna()
```

Use the following instead:

```
df['col1','col2']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a more efficient way,

```
for col in ['a', 'b']:
    v = df.loc[:, col].values
    np.nan_to_num(v, 0.0)
```