# Replace NAN with Dictionary Value for a column in Pandas using Replace() or fillna() in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and I'm trying to use fillna() functionality and facing some problem.
I have a DataFrame called Temp_Data_DF which has two columns like below:

```
Temp_Data_DF:
A  B
1  NAN
2  NAN
3  {'KEY':1,'VALUE':2}
```

I want to replace all NAN with Dict value and resulted dataframe should be like this:

```
Temp_Data_DF:
A  B
1  {'KEY':1,'VALUE':2}
2  {'KEY':1,'VALUE':2}
3  {'KEY':1,'VALUE':2}
```

I tried the below code:

```
Bvalue = {'KEY':1,'VALUE':2}
Temp_Data_DF['B']=Temp_Data_DF['B'].fillna(Bvalue)
```

But its not replacing the NAN with desired value
Any help will be appreciated.

I was refering to below link.

Link:[Pandas dataframe fillna() only some columns in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134012/pandas-dataframe-fillna-only-some-columns-in-place)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `fillna` by `Series` created by `dictionary`:

```
Bvalue = {'KEY':10,'VALUE':20}
Temp_Data_DF['B']=Temp_Data_DF['B'].fillna(pd.Series([Bvalue], index=Temp_Data_DF.index))
print (Temp_Data_DF)
   A                         B
0  1  {'VALUE': 20, 'KEY': 10}
1  2  {'VALUE': 20, 'KEY': 10}
2  3    {'VALUE': 2, 'KEY': 1}
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.Series([Bvalue], index=Temp_Data_DF.index))
0    {'VALUE': 20, 'KEY': 10}
1    {'VALUE': 20, 'KEY': 10}
2    {'VALUE': 20, 'KEY': 10}
dtype: object
```

How it working:

Idea is create new `Series` with same size like original Series filled by dictionary, so if use `fillna` by another `Series` it working nice.

Another solution: Idea is use `NaN != NaN`, so if use `if-else` in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) it replace too:

```
Bvalue = {'KEY':10,'VALUE':20}
Temp_Data_DF['B']=Temp_Data_DF['B'].apply(lambda x: x if x == x else Bvalue)
print (Temp_Data_DF)
   A                         B
0  1  {'KEY': 10, 'VALUE': 20}
1  2  {'KEY': 10, 'VALUE': 20}
2  3  {'KEY': 10, 'VALUE': 20}
```

Comment: @jezrael-it worked for me thank yo so much. aBut concept can you explain how it works

Comment: @jezrael This might be a language issue, but I think sindhu is asking for an explanation of the code, not an explanation of how to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but @jezrael's approach was not working for me.  I managed to get it work by creating a series from a list of the default dict.

```
Temp_Data_DF['B'] = Temp_Data_DF['B'].fillna(pd.Series([{'KEY':1,'VALUE':2}] * Temp_Data_DF.shape[0]))
```