# Pandas fillna() not working on DataFrame slices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

Pandas `fillna` is not working on DataFrame slices, here is an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]],
                columns=list('ABCD'))
df[["A", 'B']].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

the `DataFrame` doesn't change

```
    A   B   C   D
0   NaN 2.0 NaN 0
1   3.0 4.0 NaN 1
2   NaN NaN NaN 5
3   NaN 3.0 NaN 4
```

in contrast

```
df["A"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

and

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

work fine.

Is this a bug or does it work as intended? 
Thx in advance.

P.S. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134012/pandas-dataframe-fillna-only-some-columns-in-place) question asks **how** to use `fillna` on a slice, as for my question, it concerns **why** the above does'n work.
The answer is in @heena-bawa answers comment section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].fillna(0)

     A    B   C  D
0  0.0  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  0.0  0.0 NaN  5
3  0.0  3.0 NaN  4
```

Comment: isn't the purpose of `inplace=True` to avoid the use of assignment operator?

Comment: inplace=True for slice of a dataframe won't work. It works on complete dataframe. You have to update the slice only.

Comment: For more information, you can refer: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the [`pandas documentation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) it says you should use the following to `fillna` on slices:

```
values = {'A':0, 'B':0}
df.fillna(value=values, inplace=True)

print(df)

     A    B   C  D
0  0.0  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  0.0  0.0 NaN  5
3  0.0  3.0 NaN  4
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but I think giving a  `dict/Series` or `DF` is for "specifying which value to use for each index" and `df[["A", 'B']]` is a perfectly fine `DataFrame`. Your method is a good workaround but again my question was "Is this a bug or does it work as intended?".

Answer (score 0):

I think it works like intended. If I try your code it throws a warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  downcast=downcast, **kwargs)
```

Meaning: By selecting the columns in this way you're generating a copy and thus the parameter inplace can't have an effect.