# How to replace Nan and negative number with zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: data frame]

In the above dataframe I am trying to replace NaN and negative values in the last column with 0 using pandas, I have used some of the suggestions here, but it also seems to affect other columns and replace values in the other columns with zeroes.

How do I restrict it to just the selected column

Comment: `df.new_expenses = df.new_expenses.clip(lower=0).fillna(0)` ??

Comment: An image for a dataframe isn't useful. It's better to provide some code that creates an example dataframe.

Comment: Not sure what it means when [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) marks a duplicate, but i don't think [the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134012/pandas-dataframe-fillna-only-some-columns-in-place) is the correct one. OP's question is _not_ simply just `fillna`. Maybe it's still a duplicate of another question somewhere, but not the currently linked duplicate.

Comment: I've reopened this question @tdy as I agree with you. Community can mark a duplicate if OP accepts the proposed duplicate and close the question themselves. [Why does this question show as “marked as duplicate by Community♦”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287763/15497888)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to change negative numbers to `NaN` and then [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to `0` together with other `NaN` values in one go, as follows:

```
df['New_expenses'] = df['New_expenses'].mask(df['New_expenses'] < 0).fillna(0)
```

Or, even more simpler, credit to @tdy, using [`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) instead:

```
df['New_expenses'] = df['New_expenses'].where(df['New_expenses'] >= 0, 0)
```

[`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) keeps the values when the condition is true and replaces values when the condition is false.

In this case, we keeps the values when the values are positive and replaces the values to `0` when the condition is false (including negative numbers and `NaN` values).

Comment: @tdy  Right, that's even better.  Thanks for the very nice suggestion :-)

Comment: @tdy Thanks for the edit.  I deliberately change to `>=` to avoid the seemingly redundant action of replacing 0 to 0.    Anyway, thanks for the edit.

Comment: ah sorry, i mixed it up! you're right that `>=` avoids the redundancy, not `>`

Comment: @tdy  Yup, it's easily mixed up.  I often have this  :-D

Answer (score 2):

Use `clip` to set the negative values to a minimum, and `fillna` to replace the NAs:

```
df['New_expenses'] = df['New_expenses'].clip(lower=0).fillna(0)
```

Comment: I think `df[['New_expenses', 'Month_Expenses']] = df[['New_expenses', 'Month_Expenses']].clip(lower=0).fillna(0)` works for targeting more than one column.

Comment: Correct, however it was my understanding that only the last column was the target. But now OP had the choice ;)