# use of reverse dictionary to replace missing values

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I use the following dictionary to replace missing values in a column in my dataframe:

```py
dct = {
'Central and Eastern Europe': [
    'Albania','Bosnia and Herzegovina','Bulgaria','Croatia','Czech Republic','Estonia','Hungary','Kosovo',
    'Latvia','Lithuania','Montenegro','North Macedonia','Poland','Romania','Serbia','Slovakia','Slovenia'],
'Commonwealth of Independent States': [
    'Armenia','Azerbaijan','Belarus','Georgia','Kazakhstan','Kyrgyzstan','Moldova','Russia','Tajikistan','Turkmenistan','Ukraine','Uzbekistan'],
...
}
```

Now i use the following code to invert the dictionary:

```py
revdct = {c: r for r, lst in dct.items() for c in lst}
nan = float('NaN')
df = df.set_index('Country')['Region'].fillna(revdct).reset_index()
df
```

df only shows the dataframe with the two columns 'Country' and 'Region'
how do i get the whole dataframe printed, since it has also other columns?

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953) Sure, we can fabricate a dataframe with example data to test your/our code on, but wouldn't it be _so much easier_ if you just included a sample of your dataframe in your question?!

Answer (score 0):

when you do *`df = df.set_index('Country')['Region']`* you're reducing `df` to just the `Region` column [and `Country` as that's the index now].

Try [filling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38134049/6146136) `Region` in a separate statement

```py
df = df.set_index('Country')

df['Region'] = df['Region'].fillna(revdct)
# df['Region'].fillna(revdct, inplace=True) ## [not sure it won't set off warnings]

df = df.reset_index()
df # print(df.to_markdown(tablefmt='fancy_grid'))
```

---

You could also try using [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on `Country` instead of setting-then-resetting index.

```py
df['Region'] = df['Region'].fillna(df['Country'].map(revdct))
# df['Region'].fillna(df['Country'].map(revdct), inplace=True)

df
```

[image: samplop]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately the code didn't work. The 'Region' column didn't got filled, there are still Nan's.

Comment: @Anastasia sorry I forgot to move `reset_index` to after `fillna` - I've edited my answer and also added an alternative method with demonstration. Would you mind giving it another try?

Comment: Thank you Driftr95! I tried .map and it worked!