# Filling nulls after merge - but only to the newly merged columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I am merging:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4],
                   'Column A': [2, 3, 2, 3],
                  'Column B': [None, None, 3, None]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,4],
                   'Column C': [2, 3, 22]})
df = df.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')
df
```

The output is:

```
   ID  Column A  Column B  Column C
0   1         2       NaN       2.0
1   2         3       NaN       3.0
2   3         2       3.0       NaN
3   4         3       NaN      22.0
```

Position 2 on the new 'Column C' is Null because ID=3 does not exist in df2.

How can I fill the nulls in the new columns only but leave the nulls in the old column intact?
Expected output:

```
   ID  Column A  Column B  Column C
0   1         2       NaN       2.0
1   2         3       NaN       3.0
2   3         2       3.0       0.0
3   4         3       NaN      22.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dataframe fillna() only some columns in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134012/pandas-dataframe-fillna-only-some-columns-in-place)

Comment: No. This answer replace nulls in ALL columns, not just the new ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the IDs to generate a mask for [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')
m = ~df['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])

out[m] = out[m].fillna(0)
```

Alternatively, [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df.set_index('ID'),
                 df2.set_index('ID')
                    .reindex(df['ID'], fill_value=0)],
                axis=1)
```

Another (not as nice) option, use a placeholder (e.g. `object`) for existing NaNs:

```
out = (df.fillna(object)
         .merge(df2.fillna(object), on='ID', how='left')
         .fillna(0).replace({object: float('nan')})
       )
```

Output:

```
   ID  Column A  Column B  Column C
0   1         2       NaN       2.0
1   2         3       NaN       3.0
2   3         2       3.0       0.0
3   4         3       NaN      22.0
```