# Delete row after filtering in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe(`ratings_base`) which contains 100000 rows. I am filtering one row from it and I used following code segment for it.

`((ratings_base.loc[ratings_base['user_id'] == 1]).sort_values(by='rating', ascending=0)).iloc[0]`

which returns me a `Series` object.

```
user_id       1
movie_id    170
rating        5
Name: 19996, dtype: int64
```

How can I delete this row(Series object) from my original dataframe object ? I can use dataframe's drop function but I need row index for it. If I can get the row index of the selected row (I can see it appears as the Name attribute of the Series object), I can drop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.loc[0]` selects the first row.
`df.loc[1:]` selects everything after the first row.

So you could use

```
ratings_base = ((ratings_base.loc[ratings_base['user_id'] == 1])
                .sort_values(by='rating', ascending=0))
ratings_base = ratings_base.iloc[1:]
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `df.drop`:

```
row = ((ratings_base.loc[ratings_base['user_id'] == 1])
       .sort_values(by='rating', ascending=0)).iloc[0]
label = row.name
ratings_base = ratings_base.drop(label)
```

This may be more flexible if you wish to drop a row which does not happen to be the first.

Note that `ratings_base.drop` will drop *all* rows whose index is `label`. So more than one row may be dropped if the index is not unique.

Comment: Prefer the alternative and also it worked me. Have side question. I had to use  "inplace=True" property to get it dropped. I checked len(rating_base) to confirm whether it is dropped. Without  "inplace=True" property I saw length was 100000 and with that prop it was 99999. What is the reason?

Comment: When you call `df.drop(..., inplace=True)`, `drop` modifieds `df` and returns `None`. When you call `df.drop(...)`, `df` is not modified and `drop` returns a new DataFrame. So to change the value of `df` you would need to use an assignment: `df = df.drop(...)`. I prefer the latter (avoiding `inplace=True`) because the name `inplace` is misleading -- it is not a truly inplace operation in the sense that it does not save temporary memory. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/22533110/190597 for other reasons to avoid `inplace`.