# Pandas Dataframe Behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've checked around on the forums, but can't seem to find an answer to this:

I created some test code to add a column to a dataframe based on if 'Score' is great or equal to 9:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Score', [1,9,10]),\
 ('Response',['this is text', 'have some more text',\
                            'how about one more?'])])

df1['1 or 2'] = np.where(df1['Score'] >= 9, '1', '0')
print(df1)
```

output:

```
   Score             Response    1 or 2
0      1         this is text      0
1      9  have some more text      1
2     10  how about one more?      1
```

This works perfectly.

However, when i run the same type of code for my real data set which comes from a csv, it does not work. I get a strange output with either the index or the added column in a different "row" and an error message. Yet i don't get the error message with the test code?

Code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('C:PATH_HERE\\SOME_FILE.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')  # opens the file

df2 = df1.reset_index()  # Resets the columns to correct position

df3 = df2.dropna() # dropping the nulls
df3['1 or 2'] = np.where(df3['LIKELY_TO_RECOMMEND'] >= 9, '1', '0')

print(df3.head(n=5)) #displaying top 5 so fits on screen for Stack
```

output and error:

```
   LIKELY_TO_RECOMMEND                              VERB_REASON_FOR_SCORE  \
0                  0.0  Atendimento robotizado, nenhuma flexibilidade ...   
1                  0.0  The migration specialist, Lynette Throckmorton...   
2                  0.0           Lousy lying and no recommendable service   
3                  0.0  The new software is - not only, apparently, fu...   
4                  0.0  I feel that the portal for the garnishments is...   

  1 or 2  
0      0  
1      0  
2      0  
3      0  
4      0  

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df3['1 or 2'] = np.where(df3['LIKELY_TO_RECOMMEND'] >= 9, '1', '0')
```

Why this 'error' on the one code and not the other?

Comment: That's not a separate row, it's just wrapping in the display because the data is too wide to fit on one line.  The SettingWithCopyWarning is something you can find a gazillion questions about by searching this site or googling.

Comment: @BrenBarn in regards to the separate row, that's what I believed. In regards to the error. I'm unsure of why it's happening on this dataframe and not the other 'test' one. I have searched the issue and can't figure out why the error is not across both sets of code.

Comment: I can't reproduce the SettingWithCopyWarning.  What pandas version are you using?

Comment: version is 0.18.1. Using Conda 4.2.9 if that matters

Comment: @BrenBarn The error goes away when removing the `df.dropna()`. Any idea why this would  happen?

Comment: I was wondering about.  It is likely that the `dropna` is returning a DataFrame whose data is somehow linked to the original.  You could try doing `df3 = d2.copy().dropna()` and see if that fixes it.  It is odd though because `.dropna()` should be returning a new DataFrame as long as you don't use `inplace=True`.

Comment: @BrenBarn. That is exactly what I did. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some playing with the code I found that the reason why the SettingWithCopyWarning 'error' was appearing was due to using `dropna()`

When removing that from the code, it worked fine. Following off [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532302/pandas-peculiar-performance-drop-for-inplace-rename-after-dropna)
i used below code to remove the 'error' while still dropping the nulls in my DataFrame:

```
df3 = df2.dropna().copy()
```