# Drop columns of DataFrames from a list of DataFrames using List Comprehension (Pandas)

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a list of DataFrames that have the same columns and different values. I want to drop some columns from the list of DataFrames in one line in pandas.

For far, I tried (`dfs` has list of Data Frames)

```
dfs.drop([col for col in ['var1', 'var2'] if col in dfs], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

and

```
dfs[dfs.drop([col for col in ['var1', 'var2'] if col in dfs], axis=1, inplace=True)]
```

both are giving same error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'drop'

```
type(dfs)
>> list
```

However, when i can loop through each DataFRame from the list `dfs` using `for` loop, I can drop the columns.

How can I do it in the list comprehension way in pandas?

Comment: But `dfs` is list, not a single dataframe.

Comment: A list comprehension is not the idiomatic way to solve this problem.

Comment: `dfs` is a list of DataFrames

Comment: @COLDSPEED okay, I was wondering if I could do in list comprehension. Thanks for the suggestion, I will continue to use the regular `for` loop

Comment: @i.n.n.m Not that you can't do it... you _can_. But why?

Comment: @COLDSPEED because I have about 20 different dataframes in `dfs` I wanted to look at some dataframes with a variable that I am interested in (`'var3','var4'`) while dropping (`'var1', 'var1'`) others. Ans then I would drop `var3` and look at the rest together. This is why I wanted to drop some columns from the dataframes in `dfs`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want to drop `['var1', 'var2']` columns, and your data frames have the same columns, you should use a `for` loop.

```
for df in dfs:
    df.drop(['var1', 'var2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Alternatively, you could also use this:

```
dfs = [df.drop(['var1', 'var2'], axis=1) for df in dfs]
```

Omitting the `inplace=True` will cause `df.drop` to return a *new* dataframe, rather than updating inplace and returning None.

Comment: Will this work? Isn't the loop iterating over a copy of the list (of dataframes) instead of the actual list itself?

Comment: @AdarshChavakula When working with mutable objects like dataframes, you're working directly with the reference, and not a copy. It does indeed work.

Comment: As an exercise, create `df`, then assign `df` to `df1`. Try dropping a column in `df1`, and the change is reflected in `df` too.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks for that :) Need to learn what mutable and non-mutable objects are.

Comment: @COLDSPEED thank you, `dfs = [df.drop(['var1', 'var2'], axis=1) for df in dfs]`  list comprehension way works just fine :)

Comment: @i.n.n.m I still stand by the loop, but hey, whatever gets the job done, right? ;) More power to you.

Comment: @COLDSPEED agreed, I wanted to try the list comprehension method too for future purposes!

Comment: I agree that the list comprehension with the inplace argument is non-idiomatic but for a list of DataFrames, your last suggestion is good. The argument itself is a little misleading but it actually creates a copy under the hood so no memory savings unfortunately.

Comment: @ayhan Thank you, that was illuminating! I've edited my post.

Comment: `inplace=True` is misleadingly named -- internally, the method creates a new (sub)-DataFrame then calls [`_update_inplace`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L2279) which copies the resultant DataFrame's `_data` back into the calling DataFrame's `_data` attribute.
The `inplace=True` option persists for backwards-compatibility, but because of its misleading nature, [probably should not recommended for use going forward](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22533110/190597).

Comment: @cs95 there is any technical reason for suggesting the loop instead of the list of comprehension (time/memory ecc...)?

Comment: @AndreaCiufo I need to remove the list comprehension from the answer, list comps are not meant to be used to trigger side effects (as is being done here).