# How to delete all columns in DataFrame except certain ones?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
4  3  7  1  6  9  4
8  9  0  2  4  2  1
```

How would I go about deleting every column besides `a` and `b`?

This would result in:

```
a  b
1  2
4  3
8  9
```

I would like a way to delete these using a simple line of code that says, delete all columns besides `a` and `b`, because let's say hypothetically I have 1000 columns of data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 158):

```
In [48]: df.drop(df.columns.difference(['a','b']), 1, inplace=True)
Out[48]:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  4  3
2  8  9
```

or:

```
In [55]: df = df.loc[:, df.columns.intersection(['a','b'])]

In [56]: df
Out[56]:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  4  3
2  8  9
```

PS please be aware that [the **most idiomatic Pandas way** to do that was already proposed by @Wen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45846274/5741205):

```
df = df[['a','b']]
```

or

```
df = df.loc[:, ['a','b']]
```

Comment: is there any difference in terms of performance or something when you use inplace, a more general question would be df.drop(...inplace=True) vs df = df[...] any suggestions

Comment: @PirateApp, there might be some minimal difference. I would recommend you to read [this answer from one of the main Pandas developers Jeff and comments under that answer...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532302/pandas-peculiar-performance-drop-for-inplace-rename-after-dropna/22533110#22533110)

Comment: @MaxU I think `df.loc` is way faster than any other method like `drop` or `filter` for processing millions of records. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 106):

Another option to add to the mix. I prefer this approach for readability.

```py
df = df.filter(['a', 'b'])
```

Where the first positional argument is `items=[]`

---

#### Bonus

You can also use a `like` argument or `regex` to filter.
Helpful if you have a set of columns like `['a_1','a_2','b_1','b_2']`

You can do

```py
df = df.filter(like='b_')
```

and end up with `['b_1','b_2']`

[Pandas documentation for filter.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

Answer (score 60):

there are multiple solution .

```
df = df[['a','b']] #1

df = df[list('ab')] #2

df = df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(['a','b'])] #3

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df.eval('a,b').T,columns=['a','b']) #4 PS:I do not recommend this method , but still a way to achieve this
```

Comment: `df = df[['a','b']]` if you looking to work on subset.

Answer (score 5):

Hey what you are looking for is:

```
df = df[["a","b"]]
```

You will recive a dataframe which only contains the columns a and b

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is no different than @BENY's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45846274/8285811)'s first option.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to keep more columns than you're dropping put a "~" before the .isin statement to select every column except the ones you want:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['a','b'])]
```

Comment: This is the only answer.
"drop columns except".
Thanks, I was looking for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than two columns that you want to drop, let's say `20` or `30`, you can use lists as well. Make sure that you also specify the axis value.

```
drop_list = ["a","b"]
df = df.drop(df.columns.difference(drop_list), axis=1)
```