# Dropping Columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop all the columns in a pandas dataframe, except for these few, but when I run this code all the columns are dropped. The dataset is so big, that it would be tedious to list them all, any ideas?:

```
for columns in df:
    if not columns == 'Carbohydrates' or columns == 'Description' or columns == '1st Household Weight' or columns == 'Sugar Total' or columns == 'Kilocalories':
       df = df.drop(columns, axis = 1)
```

Comment: which columns do you want to keep?

Comment: Possible dublicate [How to delete all columns in DataFrame except certain ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45846189/5299969)

Comment: droping is not good, you can assign selected columns to variable. like this: `df = df.loc[:, ['a','b']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the parenthesis in this way:

```
if not (columns == 'Carbohydrates' or columns == 'Description' or columns == '1st Household Weight' or columns == 'Sugar Total' or columns == 'Kilocalories'):
```

Answer (score 1):

Just **select the columns** that you want to keep:

```
df = df[['Carbohydrates','Description','1st Household Weight','Sugar Total','Kilocalories']]
```