# How to loop through json and create a dataframe

Tags: json, pandas

I have a JSON file like below, how can I make a dataframe out of this. I want to make the main key an index and subkey as a column.

```
{
  "PACK": {
    "labor": "Recycle",
    "actual": 0,
    "Planned": 2,
    "max": 6
  },
  "SORT": {
    "labor": "Mix",
    "actual": 10,
    "Planned": 4,
    "max": 3
  }
}
```

The expected output is something like, I tried to use `df.T` but does not work. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
        actual  planned
PACK      0       2
SORT      10      4
```

Comment: Show you current code, please

Comment: i did df1 = pd.json_normalize(df) and its giving me 1 row with subkey as column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas can read JSON files in many formats. For your use case, the following option should read your data the way you want:

```py
pd.read_json(json_file, orient="index")
```

More information about the orient option can be found at the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can read your json file to dict. Then create dataframe with dict values as data and dict keys as index.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd


with open('test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(data.values(), index=data.keys())
```

```
print(df)

        labor  actual  Planned  max
PACK  Recycle       0        2    6
SORT      Mix      10        4    3
```

The select columns with

```py
df = df[['actual', 'planned']]
```

Comment: It's significantly faster to use `json.load(f)` instead of `json.loads(f.read())` because it doesn't need to create an intermediate string for the file contents

Comment: @AndrewMascillaro Thank you for your suggestion. BTW, your method is really a good method. Don't know that there is already built-in function for that.

Comment: If you have a lot of columns that you want to drop, you can drop all columns except those in a specific list. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846189/how-to-delete-all-columns-in-dataframe-except-certain-ones

Comment: @Oxford_orange Thank you for your suggest. But I think selecting the targeted columns and dropping the unwanted column have the same effect.

Comment: Yes,  the alternative of only keeping columns in a list is helpful with complex and variable datasets.