# How do I copy across a row a value unless it is already present?

Tags: pandas

Imagine two series:

```
A   B
0   nan
1   nan
0   3
1   8
```

How do I copy to column B the entries which appear in column A, unless that index has something already present in column B?

The only way I can think of to do this is using apply, like as follows, which seemingly is frowned upon by everyone.

```
df['B'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['A'] if r['B'].isnull() else r['B'], axis=1)
```

Comment: `df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(df['A'])` should do.

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something in the library. I ended up going with `df['B'].fillna(df['A'], inplace=True)` . Thanks!

Comment: I personally am not a big fan of [`inplace=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532302/pandas-peculiar-performance-drop-for-inplace-rename-after-dropna/22533110#22533110). But that;s whole other discussion. Glad, I could help. :)