# Speed of assignment and `inplace` in `pandas`

Tags: python, pandas, in-place

I am a fan of `inplace=True` in `pandas`. But I am wondering what is the preferred way of altering a `DataFrame`? Which one is faster? Is it better to assign to itself or use `inplace`?

Comment: Read also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533110/1534017) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Cleb for that link.  I wholeheartedly agree with what Jeff says in that answer.