# Trying to understand changing column name with inplace = true vs false

Tags: python, pandas, rename

As I understand it, when I'm changing a column name, the decision to set inplace to true or false depends on whether I want to mutate the original dataframe (`inplace=True`) or create a new dataframe object (`inplace=False`).

I have a source file in xlsx where the column names I want for my dataframe are in row 2. I need to change one of the column names so it conforms with the rest of the analysis.

```
df_original = pd.read_excel('filepath.xlsx', sheet_name = "LookUpReferences", skiprows = 1)
df_original = df_original.rename(columns = {'WrongName': 'CorrectName'}, inplace = True)
```

When I do this and, for example, look at output via the `head()` function, I get

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

I can resolve this by creating a new dataframe and setting `inplace=False`, i.e.

```
df_new = df_original.rename(columns = {'WrongName': 'CorrectName'}, inplace = False)
```

But this will get cumbersome. So I'm trying to understand why the `inplace=True` isn't working the way I want it to. Is it the skiprows portion of the read_excel() ??? That's the only reason I can think of why I'm getting a NoneType. But, very much like Jon Snow, I know nothing...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said yourself, `inplace=True` mutates the original dataframe, thus you don't have to re-assign it. 
On the other hand, the default setting is `inplace=False`, thus you can rename (and re-assign ) as:

```
df_new = df_original.rename(columns = {'WrongName': 'CorrectName'})
```

I am not sure if this is also too cumbersome for you.

Moreover as explained here [inplace performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532302/pandas-peculiar-performance-drop-for-inplace-rename-after-dropna), there is no guarantee that an inplace operation runs faster.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I suppose I'm trying to figure out why I can't use head() after I have renamed a column and set inplace = True