# Why is renaming columns in pandas so slow?

Tags: pandas

Given a large data frame (in my case 250M rows and 30 cols), why is it so slow to just change then name of a column?

I am using `df.rename(columns={'oldName':'newName'},inplace=True)` so this should not make any copies of the data, yet it is taking over 30 seconds, while I would have expected this to be in the order of milliseconds (as it's just replacing one string by another).

I know, that' a huge table, more than most people have RAM in their machine (hence I'm not going to add example code either), but still this shouldn't take any significant amount of time as it's not actually touching any of the data. Why does this take so long, i.e. why is *renaming* a column doing effort proportional to the *number of rows* of my dataframe?

Comment: Try renaming your columns by not using `inplace`: `df = df.rename(columns={'oldName':'newName'})`

Comment: Also performance [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532302/pandas-peculiar-performance-drop-for-inplace-rename-after-dropna/22533110#22533110) shows rename with `inplace` is actually slower than without.

Comment: @Quang Hoang: It does not show that. After the uncertainty of .dropna is eliminated renaming inplace is faster. My own tests confirm that, especially for large dataframes.
I used Python 3.96 and pandas 1.3.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think `inplace=True` doesn't copy your data. There are some discussion on SO saying it actually does copy, and then assign back. Also see [this github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

You can just override the columns with:

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace({'a':'b'})
```

Comment: On github it says "Should be able to not copy memory " for df.rename...