# Any issues with renaming dataframe columns using inplace=True?

Tags: pandas

Much has been written about the downsides of using `inplace=True` when working on data frames, but am I mistaken to assume that renaming columns with inplace=True is benign?
Do any data blocks get copied and discarded when I do

```
df.rename(columns={'old': 'new'}, inplace=True)
```

Simple timing tests show that renaming columns in place is faster than assigning a copy:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'old': 'new'})
```

Much faster actually for large data frames. The time renaming in place takes does not depend on the size of the dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

# np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**6,5), columns=list('abcde'))
d1 = dict(zip(list('abcde'),list('ABCDE')))
d2 = dict(zip(list('ABCDE'),list('abcde')))
t0 = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(10):
    df.rename(columns=d1, inplace=True)
    df.rename(columns=d2, inplace=True)
t1 = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(10):
    df = df.rename(columns=d1)
    df = df.rename(columns=d2)
t2 = time.perf_counter()
print('inplace :  ', t1-t0)
print('df = df :  ', t2-t1)
```

I am using Python 3.9.6 and Pandas 1.3.1. under Win10 and get:

```
inplace :   0.003490000000000215
df = df :   0.1703701999999998
```

Can I conclude that no copies are made behind the scenes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not

Comment: @lummers: As I said, much has been written.
The most relevant post to my question is 8 years old and possibly obsolete: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532302/pandas-peculiar-performance-drop-for-inplace-rename-after-dropna?noredirect=1&lq=1
And it does not answer the question. I would think column labels are metadata and editing should not require memory allocations for the data blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The time renaming in place takes does not depend on the size of the dataframe. Can I conclude that no copies are made behind the scenes?

Yes, you can conclude that, except that a copy of the column names series may be made.  Obviously the performance of that should be immaterial as the number of columns is usually not huge.