# Assign a Row to Data Frame Header that Starts with a Specific String from Excel- Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, header

I have many excel files that are in different formats. Some of them look like this, which is normal with one header can be read into `pandas`.

```
# First Column Second Column  Address            City      State Zip           
1 House        The Clairs     4321 Main Street   Chicago   IL    54872
2 Restaurant   The Monks      6323 East Wing     Miluakee  WI    45458
```

and some of them are in various formats with multiple headers,

```
Table 1
Comp    ID Info
# First Column  Second Column  Address            City      State Zip           
1 Office        The Fairs      1234 Main Street   Seattle   WA    54872
2 College       The Blanks     4523 West Street   Madison   WI    45875         
3 Ground        The Brewers    895 Toronto Street Madrid    IA    56487         


Table2                                  
Comp    ID Info         
# First Column  Second Column  Address            City      State   Zip         
1 College       The Banks      568 Old Street     Cleveland OH      52125           
2 Professional  The Circuits   695 New Street     Boston    MA      36521
```

This looks like this in Excel (I am pasting the image here to show how it actually looks in excel),
[image]

As you can see above there are three different levels of headers. For sure every file has a row that starts with `First Column`.

For an individual file like this, I can read like below, which is just fine.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(r'mypath\myfile.xlsx')    
df = pd.read_excel('xls', 'mysheet',  header=[2])
```

However, I need a final data frame like this (Appended with files that have only one header),

```
   First Column  Second Column  Address            City      State Zip
 0 House         The Clair      4321 Main Street   Chicago   IL    54872
 1 Restaurant    The Monks      6323 East Wing     Milwaukee WI    45458        
 2 Office        The Fairs      1234 Main Street   Seattle   WA    54872
 3 College       The Blanks     4523 West Street   Madison   WI    45875            
 4 Ground        The Brewers    895 Toronto Street Madrid    IA    56487
 5 College       The Banks      568 Old Street     Cleveland OH    52125            
 6 Professional  The Circuits   695 New Street     Boston    MA    36521
```

Since I have many files, I want to read each file in my folder and clean them up by getting only one header from a row. Had I knew the index position of the row, that I need as head, I could simply do something like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147180/convert-row-to-column-header-for-pandas-dataframe).

However, as some of those files can have Multiple headers (I showed 2 extra headers in above example, some have 4 headers) in different formats, I want to iterate through the file and set the row that starts with `First Column` to be header in the beginning of the file.

Additionally, I want to drop those rows that are in the middle of the the file that has `First Column`.

After I create a cleaned file headers starting with `First Column`, I can append each data frame and create my output file I need. How can I achieve this in `pandas`? Any help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: One way: read all rows in with `header=None` and your customize column-names. then filter out all rows based on the first column (i.e. `col1`): df = df[df.col1.astype(str).str.match('^\d+$')]