# How to label rows by column name

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to put column names for each row in pandas dataframe. To illustrate, my data is like

```
A | B | C
1 | 4 | 7
2 | 5 | 8
3 | 6 | 9
```

Trying to convert to :

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 4
B 5
B 6
C 7
C 8
```

Thank you

Comment: Try  with df.melt()

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147180/convert-row-to-column-header-for-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.melt`:

```
print(df.melt())
```

Or use `pd.melt`:

```
print(pd.melt(df))
```

Both reproduce:

```
  variable  value
0        A      1
1        A      2
2        A      3
3        B      4
4        B      5
5        B      6
6        C      7
7        C      8
8        C      9
```

Comment: @gartuns Accept it if it works

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is your `data-frame` like this:

```
import pandas as pd

x= pd.DataFrame ([[1,4,5],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]])
x.columns = ['A','B','C']
print(x)

   A  B  C
0  1  4  5
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

At the first, you should `append` `value of x` and `columns of x` in two separate lists such as `a` and `b`:

```
a = []
b = []

for i in range(0,len(x)):
    for j in range(0,len(x.columns)):
        a.append(x.iloc[i][j])
        b.append(x.columns[j]) 
print(a)
print(b)
[1, 4, 5, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

Now a is your list that you want and b is indexes of a. So, you can build your data-frame in this way:

```
f= pd.DataFrame(a)
f.index=b
```

If you want to sort it you can try this code:

```
print(f.sort_index())

A  1
A  2
A  3
B  4
B  5
B  6
C  5
C  8
C  9
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @gartuns Accept it if it works

Comment: Please vote up if it works. You just accepted my solution.