# How can i set second row as a name of columns in DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

How i can make from this DataFrame:
(try `df.drop([0]), df.iloc[1:]` but dont work)

```
     A B C
  0  1 2 3
  1  X Y Z
```

this:

```
     1 2 3
  0  X Y Z
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert row to column header for Pandas DataFrame,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147180/convert-row-to-column-header-for-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in two steps,

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]

df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)


print(df)

   1  2  3
0  X  Y  Z
```

a better method would be to use `skiprows` in your read argument.

```
from io import StringIO
d = """   A B C
    1 2 3
    X Y Z"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),sep='\s+',skiprows=1)
print(df)

   1  2  3
0  X  Y  Z
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, [`DataFrame.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
df.T.set_index(0).T.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)
   1  2  3
0  X  Y  Z
```