# Is there any way to set row to column-row in DataFrame? or How to get DataFrame from Excel file with setting any index row to column_row?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

Q1) Is there any way to set row to column-row in DataFrame?

```
     (DF)                                      (DF)
   A  B  C  D                                a  b  c  d
0  a  b  c  d       pandas function       0  4  5  3  6
1  4  5  3  6 ==========================> 1  3  2  5  3
2  3  2  5  3  0-idx row to columns-row   2  4  7  9  0
3  4  7  9  0
```

Q2) How to get DataFrame from Excel file with setting any index row to column_row?

```
(EXCEL or CSV)                                 (DF)
   A  B  C  D                                a  b  c  d
0  a  b  c  d       pd.read_excel()       0  4  5  3  6
1  4  5  3  6 ==========================> 1  3  2  5  3
2  3  2  5  3  0-idx row to columns-row   2  4  7  9  0
3  4  7  9  0
```

Comment: How to set row to header:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147180/convert-row-to-column-header-for-pandas-dataframe
for the second when reading specify ```header=true```

Comment: thanks, i saw your link and i could solve Q2 by adding parameter 'header'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it:

```
import pandas as pd
data={"A":['a',4,3,4],"B":['b',5,2,7],"C":['c',3,5,9],"D":['d',6,3,0]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

#define the column name from line index 0
df.columns=df.iloc[0].tolist()
#remove the line index 0
df = df.drop(0)
```

result:

```
   a  b  c  d
1  4  5  3  6
2  3  2  5  3
3  4  7  9  0
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job:

```
new_header = df.iloc[0] #first_row
df = df[1:] #remaining_dataframe
df.columns = new_header
```