# Only keep one column header in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, header

I have read my data from the s3 bucket into the lambda function using

```
tickets = s3_client.get_object(
     Bucket=bucket, Key=file_h)["Body"].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
```

then I used

```
tickets=pd.DataFrame(list(reader(tickets, delimiter=',')))
```

to convert it to a pandas dataframe. I only want one header but when I print the dataframe it shows that it has two headers. How can I only keep the second header with the names? Same with the indices, how can I only keep one?

| 0 |  | 1 | ... | 13 | 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | kennzeichen1 | ... | Lat | Long |
| 1 | 0 | M | ... | 50.9347582 | 6.9456628 |
| 2 | 1 | SU | ... | 50.9350537 | 6.9439027 |
| 3 | 2 | BM | ... | 36.12707109999999 | -79.86071799999999 |

Comment: what is the output of `list(reader(tickets, delimiter=','))`?

Comment: something like this: ```ln, ADOLPHSTR., 23', '50.9354076', '6.976208600000001'], ['9991', 'N', 'PKW', 'MERCEDES', 'GOTENRING', '8', '113140',```

Comment: I tried ```tickets.columns = tickets.columns.droplevel(-1) ```  but get: [ERROR] ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.

Comment: Since its comma separated data you could use the pd.read_csv() function.  Alternatively there are a few nice ways of setting column headers in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147180/convert-row-to-column-header-for-pandas-dataframe