# Deleting first two rows of a dataframe after doing groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete the first two rows from my dataframe `df` and am using the answer suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396903/delete-first-three-rows-of-a-dataframe-in-pandas). However, I get the error `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'ix' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method` and don't know how to do this with the `apply` method. I've  shown the relevant lines of code below:

```
df = df.groupby('months_to_maturity')
df = df.ix[2:]
```

**Edit**: Sorry, when I mean I want to delete the first two rows,  I should have said I want to delete the first two rows associated with each `months_to_maturity` value.

Thank You

Comment: You mean you want to ignore the first two groups? What manner of aggregation were you planning on doing to those groups? note that you are redefining `df` each line.

Comment: The groupby object essentially just holds metadata about how to perform the groupby so what you are trying won't work. What do you mean by first 2 rows? You could do `df = df.groupby('months_to_maturity', as_index=False)` which will allow you to remove the first 2 rows on your next line

Comment: @EdChum I apologize. I've added more info to the question.

Comment: So does `df = df.groupby('months_to_maturity', as_index=False)
df = df.ix[2:]` work?

Comment: @EdChum I get the same error as before unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

That is what `tail(-2)` will do. However, `groupby.tail` does not take a negative value, so it needs a tweak:

```
df.groupby('months_to_maturity').apply(lambda x: x.tail(-2))
```

This will give you desired dataframe but its index is a multi-index now. 
If you just want to drop the rows in `df`, just use `drop` like this:

```
df.drop(df.groupby('months_to_maturity').head(2).index)
```