# range not outputing last number

Tags: python, for-loop, range

Here is my code?

```
for i in range (10,20,2):
    print(i)
```

The output should be like this

```
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

But output is coming:

```
10
12
14
16
18
```

Why `20` is not coming?

Comment: You need to replace 20 with 22

Comment: This answer should help with the intuition: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4504677/3019689

Comment: Did it ever occur to you to [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)? *"If `step` is positive, the last element is the largest `start + i * step` **less than `stop`**"* (emphasis mine). It is even more explicit in [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function): *"The given end point is never part of the generated list"*.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `range` is exclusive (not included).  You would need to set `stop` equal to `22`:

```
for i in range(10,22,2):
    print(i)
```

to have `20` be in the output:

```
>>> for i in range(10,22,2):
...     print(i)
...
10
12
14
16
18
20
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function always prints upto the max val

```
for i in range (10,22,2):
    print(i)
```

This will print as expected

```
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

Answer (score -1):

The maximum value is not included. If you want 20 to appear, you'll need 20+1 as max value.