# Number of feature_importances_ does not match no of features in Scikit learn's DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, decision-tree

I fitted a decision tree to a dataset having 20 inputs and 1 categorical output using the following Python Code (wordsDatum is just an array containing inputs in columns 0 to 19 and the output in column 20

```
clsfr=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2,min_samples_leaf=50)
clsfr=clsfr.fit(wordsDatum[:,0:19],wordsDatum[:,20])
for items in clsfr.feature_importances_:
    print items
```

When I print the feature importances, I only get 19 values - this is strange considering I have 20 features. Any ideas what might be going on here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is due to how lists are defined in python. You can find some good insights on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end).

But in summary, if you define a list like this:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and you call `my_list[0:5]`, it will give you:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So if you change the second line of your code to:

`clsfr=clsfr.fit(wordsDatum[:,0:20],wordsDatum[:,20])`

It will do what you expect of it. It will include the first twenty features.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response! Yes, python seems to have this quirk (?) of including the lower limit but excluding the upper limit of the range