# Printing in a if else statement within a loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, printing

When I try to make it print the items within the list it never runs the first if statement. Here is my code. `number_of_numbers_multiplication` is equal to `number_of_numbers_multiplication` so it shouldn't go to the 2nd statement right?

```
numbers = [3,2,1]
how_many_multiplication = 3
number_of_numbers_multiplication = int(how_many_multiplication)
first = True
for multiplication_printer in range (1,number_of_numbers_multiplication):
            if multiplication_printer == number_of_numbers_multiplication:
                    print(numbers[multiplication_printer])
            elif multiplication_printer > 1 and multiplication_printer != number_of_numbers_multiplication:
                    print(numbers[multiplication_printer],'multiplied by,')
            elif first == True:
                    print(numbers[0],'multiplied by,')
                    print(numbers[1],'multiplied by,')
                    first = False;
```

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does range(start, end) not include end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal. The stop parameter `number_of_numbers_multiplication` of the [range function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) is exclusive. If you want to reach it, use `range(1,number_of_numbers_multiplication+1)`.

**EDIT:** Now, since you changed the value of number_of_numbers_multiplication and it is equal to 3. The solution would be to use `range(1,number_of_numbers_multiplication)` but use `if multiplication_printer==number_of_numbers_multiplication-1`

**EDIT 2** The important things to keep in mind are:

1.`multiplication_printer` is used as an index, so it must stop at the length of the list-1 (3-1=2).
2. the stop parameter of range is exclusive, so if `multiplication_printer` must stop at 2, the parameter must be equal to 3.

Comment: but then it prints 3 multiplied by 2 multiplied by 1 multiplied by instead of 3 multiplied by 2 multiplied by 1

Comment: if we go with number_of_numbers_multiplication, without the +1, we will have only one iteration. And it will execute the third statement. That would happen because multiplication printer would be equal to 1 and first=True. We won't have any other iterations because multiplication_printer goes from 1 to 2 exclusive, which means he never reaches 2.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer to match the last edit of your question

Comment: Sorry for only accepting this now, I was new to stack overflow and must've not realised or forgot, thanks again.