# range(1,n+2) not printing my desired output in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not getting expected output in below code. It should print up to 7 but it is not printing.

[image: Here is the output screenshot]

```
n=5
for i in range(1,n+2):
    for j in range(1,i):
        print(j, end='')
    print("\n")
```

Comment: *" it should print till 7"*.. so `n = 7` ? Any reason why you used `n=5` ?

Comment: Range's stopping point is *ex*clusive - `i` is at most `6`, `j` is at most `5`. If you want to print up to `7`... `n = 7`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does range(start, end) not include end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I didn't understand why you used `n=5`, when `n=7` do the work, exactly like you wanted. I saw that you already have the answer using `n=5` so I'm putting here a a solution with `n=7` with some prints that will help you to understand what is happening inside these two nested loops.

```py
n = 7
for i in range(1, n+2):
    for j in range(1, i):
        print("j:", j, end =" ")
    print("i:", i)
    print("***")
```

The output will be:

```
i: 1
***
j: 1 i: 2
***
j: 1 j: 2 i: 3
***
j: 1 j: 2 j: 3 i: 4
***
j: 1 j: 2 j: 3 j: 4 i: 5
***
j: 1 j: 2 j: 3 j: 4 j: 5 i: 6
***
j: 1 j: 2 j: 3 j: 4 j: 5 j: 6 i: 7
***
j: 1 j: 2 j: 3 j: 4 j: 5 j: 6 j: 7 i: 8
```

Did you notice what happens when `for j in range(1, 1)` ? no `j` is printed, so `for j in range(1, 2)`, prints `1` for `j` and `i` is `2`.

That's why your code with `n = 5` was not working. When `i` is `6`, `j` is `5` and for i in range(1, 7) only goes till i=6.

```
n = 5
for i in range(1, n+2):
    for j in range(1, i):
        print("j:", j, end =" ")
    print("i:", i)
    print("***")
```

The output:

```
i: 1
***
j: 1 i: 2
***
j: 1 j: 2 i: 3
***
j: 1 j: 2 j: 3 i: 4
***
j: 1 j: 2 j: 3 j: 4 i: 5
***
j: 1 j: 2 j: 3 j: 4 j: 5 i: 6
***
```

But, I really think you should get used to work with 0 based ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in the range() function is a stop value.  It will not be included in the loop.  So, your loops need to add 1 to the second parameter of both ranges:

```
n=5
for i in range(1,n+2 + 1):
    for j in range(1,i + 1):
        print(j, end='')
    print("\n")
```

You should get used to using zero based ranges however:

```
n=5
for i in range(n+2):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(j+1, end='')
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

for i in range(1,n+2)
n+2 is incorrect syntax so make a new variable called x and assine it n+2 EG.:

`x = n + 2`

To get numbers up to 7, x must equal n + 4 EG.:

```
n=5
x = n + 4
for i in range(1,x):
    for j in range(1,i):
        print(j, end='')
        print("\n")
```

Also indentations are imprtant in python.

Comment: I think that "for i in range" will go up to x but not include it so x must equal two greater than the desired output.