# Python splicing list does not include first element when working backwards

Tags: python, list, splice

```
new_list = [i + 1 for i in range(16)]

sec_list = new_list[(len(new_list) - 2):0:-2]

print(new_list)

print(sec_list)
```

**Actual Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

[15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3]
```

**Desired output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

[15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1] <---- I want the 1 to be present
```

Just want to clarify how this works. I thought [start: end: increment/decrement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need

```
sec_list = new_list[(len(new_list) - 2)::-2]
print(sec_list) # [15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

You made a mistake in second argument:

```
new_list[(len(new_list) - 2):0:-2]
```

start: `(len(new_list) - 2)`
stop: 0
step: -2

which means that you stopped on 0 item that's why 1 was not included

also you can read about this [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end)

Comment: Because that's how ranges work: they include the start, but not the end. `range(16)` (equivalently, `range(0, 16, 1)`) is from 0 to 15. In the same way, `range(16, 0, -1)` is from 16 to 1. Note also that you can replace `len(new_list) - 2` with just `-2`. You can compact everything like this: `new_list = list(range(1, 17)); sec_list = new_list[-2::-2]`