# Printing out all unicode emojis to file

Tags: python, unicode, emoji, chr, ord

It's possible to print the hexcode of the emoji with `u'\uXXX'` pattern in Python, e.g.

```
>>> print(u'\u231B')
⌛
```

However, if I have a list of hex code like `231B`, just "adding" the string won't work:

```
>>> print(u'\u' + ' 231B')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

The `chr()` fails too:

```
>>> chr('231B')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

My first part of the question is **given the hexcode, e.g. `231A` how do I get the `str` type of the emoji?**

My goal is to getting the list of emojis from https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.0/emoji-sequences.txt and read the hexcode on the first column.

There are cases where it ranges from `231A..231B`, the second part of my question is **given a hexcode range, how do I iterate through the range to get the emoji `str`**, e.g. `2648..2653`, it is possible to do `range(2648, 2653+1)` but if there's a character in the hexa, e.g. `1F232..1F236`, using `range()` is not possible.

---

Thanks @amadan for the solutions!!

### TL;DR

To get a list of emojis from https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.0/emoji-sequences.txt into a file.

```py
import requests
response = requests.get('https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.0/emoji-sequences.txt')

with open('emoji.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in response.content.decode('utf8').split('\n'):
        if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#'):
            hexa = line.split(';')[0]
            hexa = hexa.split('..')            
            if len(hexa) == 1:
                ch = ''.join([chr(int(h, 16)) for h in hexa[0].strip().split(' ')])
                print(ch, end='\n', file=fout)
            else:
                start, end = hexa
                for ch in range(int(start, 16), int(end, 16)+1):
                    #ch = ''.join([chr(int(h, 16)) for h in ch.split(' ')])
                    print(chr(ch), end='\n', file=fout)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert hex string to number, then use `chr`:

```
chr(int('231B', 16))
# => '⌛'
```

or directly use a hex literal:

```
chr(0x231B)
```

To use a range, again, you need an int, either converted from a string or using a hex literal:

```
''.join(chr(c) for c in range(0x2648, 0x2654))
# => '♈♉♊♋♌♍♎♏♐♑♒♓'
```

or

```
''.join(chr(c) for c in range(int('2648', 16), int('2654', 16)))
```

(NOTE: you'd get something *very* different from `range(2648, 2654)`!)

Comment: Does `int('2654', 16)` include 2654?

Comment: It is an integer, it doesn't have a concept of inclusion. `int('2654', 16)` is equal to `0x2654` and 9812, representing the code point `'WHITE CHESS KING'`. If you are asking if `range(0x2648, 0x2654)` includes `0x2654`, then no, it does not, since `range` never includes its endpoint; see [Why does range(start, end) not include end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end)

Comment: Ah, but the range does include in unicode emoji. so `int('2654', 16) + 1` =)

Comment: No, you said `2648..2653`; I already added the needed 1. If you want, you can write `int('2653', 16) + 1`.

Comment: Ah yes, my fault, didn't read the range properly. You're write, it's already +1 =)

Comment: How about emojis like `00A9 FE0F`?

Comment: Those are just two characters next to each other: `chr(0xa9) + chr(0xfe0f)`.