# convention range value in python

Tags: python, for-loop, range

i can't understand this convention range in python,  range(len(s) -1) for representing all elements including the last one. For me makes no sense like when I print all elements the last one is not included in the list. Someone could help me understand this logic?

## this>

```
s = "abccdeffggh"
for i in range(len(s) -1):
    print(i)
```

## result this

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end

Comment: `range(3)` iterates 3 times.  `range(len(s) - 1)` iterates `len(s) - 1` times.  What's confusing about that?

Comment: Why are you using `len(s) - 1`?  That specifically tells it to use one _less_ than the number of elements, so of course it skips the last one.

Comment: def count_adjacent_repeats(s):
    ''' (str) -> int

    Return the number of occurrences of a character and
    an adjacent character being the same.

    >>> count_adjacent_repeats('abccdeffggh')
    3
    '''

    repeats = 0

    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        if s[i] == s[i + 1]:
            repeats = repeats + 1

    return repeats

Comment: because I need to interate with all elements inclusive with the stop element in this function.
Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to print range  to compiler you saying like this print numbers greter than 1 and below than 10 to the output not include 1 and 10 compiler only print 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in your case

```
s = "abccdeffggh"
```

this s string length must be 11 if you print like this

```
s = "abccdeffggh"
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(i)
```

you get output as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 that is the numbers between 0 and 11

but in your code you have subtract -1 from the length  then your range is become -1 and 10 then compiler print all numbers between the -1 and 10 it not include -1 and 10

try this code

```
s = "abccdeffggh"
print(len(s))
print(len(s)-1)
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: I need to interate with all str elements in this function:
but the range functions stops at the last element..

def count_adjacent_repeats(s):
    ''' (str) -> int

    Return the number of occurrences of a character and
    an adjacent character being the same.

    >>> count_adjacent_repeats('abccdeffggh')
    3
    '''

    repeats = 0

    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        if s[i] == s[i + 1]:
            repeats = repeats + 1

    return repeats

Thanks for your feedback.