# I am trying to use a for loop in python to calculate the sum of a summation series. [via Jupyter Notebook]

Tags: python

[Image of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U76Kl.png)

I am trying to use a for loop to calculate the sum as the total number of values in the series increase by the power of 10. My code so far does not calculate anything. I apologise. I'm new to Python and still learning. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

This is my code:

```
i = 1
sum = 100

for num in range((-1)^(i+1)):
    sum += num
print("The sum of the first ", i, "numbers is: ", sum )
```

**EDIT** Hello, thank you for all your help! But it seems like for my problem, I need to individually print out all three of the summations using the for loop. Could I perhaps ask for help on this part? Thank you so much!

Comment: Power operator in python is **

Answer (score 2):

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 100+1):
    sum += ((-1)**(i+1))/i
print(sum)
```

Comment: I am glad this snipped helped, read more about [range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end) here

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can start with this (the first one):
First create a dummy variable which will collect your result - here I call sum.
Next just loop over the required number of times.
(Note that the power in python is ** and not ^)

```
    sum =0
    for i in range(1,100):
       sum+=((-1)**(i+1))/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way using Lists (one line of code :) )

```
print(sum([(-1)**(i+1) for i in range(1,100)]))
```