# Python's range is half-open (start included, stop excluded)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Write a script that prints every even numbers between 1 and 100 inclusive, one per line

```
nums=list(range(1,100))
for i in nums:
    if i%2 ==0:
        print(i)
```

result:Python's range is half-open (start included, stop excluded).
**why and how**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does range(start, end) not include end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end)

Answer (score 1):

Since the stop value is not included, you can just increment the stop value to include the desired value. So, if you want to include "100", you must provide a stop value of **"101"**.

```
nums = range(1, 101)
```

Also, you don't necessarily need `list()` here.

Comment: You should add that he doesn't need nums he can just have the `range(1,101)` directly in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
nums=list(range(1,101))
for i in nums:
   if i%2 ==0:
       print(i)
```

Comment: Maybe a summary about "why" can provide a lot more value than just writing code without any explanations.