# For loop does not calculate the max multiple

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working through the Max Multiple challenge on Code Signal:

> Given a `divisor` and a `bound`, find the largest integer `N` such that:
>
> `N` is divisible by `divisor`. `N` is less than or equal to `bound`. `N` is
> greater than 0. It is guaranteed that such a number exists.
>
> Example
>
> For `divisor = 3` and `bound = 10`, the output should be
> `maxMultiple(divisor, bound) = 9`.
>
> The largest integer divisible by 3 and not larger than 10 is 9.

This is my attempt:

```
def maxMultiple(divisor, bound):

    largest = 0

    for i in range(0,bound):
        if i % divisor == 0 and i <= bound:
            largest = i

    print(largest)
```

It passes on most tests but fails on these ones:

```
Input: divisor: 8
       bound: 88
Output: null
Expected Output:88
Console Output:80
```

```
Input:divisor: 10
      bound: 100
Output: null
Expected Output: 100
Console Output: 90
```

I am checking for the constraints in my if statement but it fails on these two cases. I do not understand why.

Comment: `range(0, bound)` goes from `0` to `bound - 1`

Comment: `range(0, bound)` only iterates up to `bound-1`...  also you might want to consider iterating downwards and returning the first match instead to be more efficient

Comment: Why looping, what about bound - (bound % divisor)?

Comment: `range(0, bound)` not include `bound`, or you can use `range(0, bound+1)`. Another `range(bound, 0, -1)` may be better, it will be max one found and no more searching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does range(start, end) not include end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try running the loop from 1 to bound+1

```
def maxMultiple(divisor, bound):
    
        largest = 0
    
        for i in range(1,bound+1):
            if i % divisor == 0 and i <= bound:
                largest = i
    
        print(largest)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your `range`.  You're iterating from `0` through `bound-1`, when in fact you need to iterate from `1` through `bound`.  You also don't need the in-loop bound test, since the `range` should cover it.  The following should work:

```
def maxMultiple(divisor, bound):
    largest = None

    for i in range(1,bound+1):
        if i % divisor == 0:
            largest = i

    return largest
```

But a better way to do it is to iterate from high to low, as follows:

```
def maxMultiple(divisor, bound):
    for i in range(bound, 0, -1):
        if i % divisor == 0:
            return i

    return None
```

You could also dispense with the loop altogether:

```
def maxMultiple(divisor, bound):
    return (bound // divisor) * divisor
```

Or equivalently:

```
def maxMultiple(divisor, bound):
    return bound - (bound % divisor)
```

Answer (score 2):

The second `range` boundary is exclusive. So to include `bound`, you need

```
range(foo, bound+1)
```

Even better is looping from the back, here seen using `next`:

```
def maxMultiple(divisor, bound):
    return next(i for i in range(bound, 0, -1) if not i % divisor)
```

But, you can actually directly calculate this without any loop, using floor division:

```
def maxMultiple(divisor, bound):
    return (bound // divisor) * divisor
```