# Slicing by an increment of -2 not working

Tags: python

In the case of this function starting from -2 position, it should print [115,43].

```
def increment(nums):


    t = (nums[-2:-4:-2 ])
    print(t)

    print(increment([43, 90, 115, 500]))
```

However, the output for this code is just [115], how come?

Comment: Remember, Python ranges are exclusive of the second bound.  To get the behavior you indicated, replace -4 with -5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does range(start, end) not include end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `[-2:-4:-1]`, you can see that the result is `[115, 90]` and `43` is not included. That's because python ranges are exclusive of the second bound.

If you want to include `43`, you should use `[-2:-5:-2]`. Then the result would be `[115, 43]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
def increment(nums):
    print(nums[-2:-5:-2]) # output: [115, 43]

increment([43, 90, 115, 500])
```

slicing in python: `slice(start, end, step)`

when you give `nums[-2:-4:-2 ]` python will start from `115` and jumps `2` positions  to the `left` and reach at `43` but you have set the end as `90 (-4 will go upto -3 position, not 43)`

So, I just changed the `end index` to `-5`