# Python List Indexing: What's the advantage of using Inclusive index for lower bound, and Exclusive index for upper bound?

Tags: python, list, indexing

For example, in the `range(0, 6)` function, we only generate number from 0 to 5. 0 is included, but 6 is excluded.

Also I see this in list slicing. That `mylist[:6]`, index 0-5 in included, but index 6 is excluded.

What are the benefits of such indexing mechanisms? I find it strange because lower bound is included, while upper bound is excluded.

Comment: I think there are some good answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end).

Comment: The choice is an irrelevant design decision.  What's important is to be consistent, and Python is.

Answer (score 1):

At heart it's simply elegant, and less error-prone when you're used to it. For example, for indices `L <= R`, the slice `s[L:R]` has `R-L` elements, while for any integer `j` with `L <= j <= R`, the slice can be decomposed as `s[L:R] == s[L:j] + s[j:R]`.

Those straightforward properties save the experienced from a world of off-by-1 errors.