# Why is the last index value is not processed in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

In Python For loop, the last index value is not processed. Why?

```
to=np.shape(aStaffs)[0]-1   # gives 4 (5 items, but I do not use index 0)
print("to:",to,"  ",end=" ")

for stf in range(1,to,1):
    print("stf:",stf,"  ",end=" ")  
# BUT stf only gives, 1,2,3, not 4
```

Comment: The for loop isn't doing anything funny. The `range` object specifies a _semi-open_ interval `[start, stop)`. The `stop` value is not included in the range

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does range(start, end) not include end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504662/why-does-rangestart-end-not-include-end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `range` function returns a half-open interval, meaning either the `start` value or the `stop` value is included but not both. [The range() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) says,

> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and **r[i] < stop.**

You can get the range to include the last index value by incrementing your `stop` parameter: `range(1,to+1,1)`.

Comment: But when I add+1, I get an overindex error. So, it was unsolvable.  For now I switched on a While loop. I'll take your answer into account. . Thanks.